# Password Protection Python

Tags: python, encryption, passwords

I have a small python program which will be used locally by a small group of people (<15 people).But for accountability, i want to have a simple username+password check at the start of the program ( doesn't need to be super secure).For your information, I am just a beginner and this is my first time trying it.When i search around, i found that python has passlib for encryption. But even after looking though it i am still not sure how to implement my encryption.So, there are a few things that i want to know.

1. How do i store the passwords of users locally? The only way i know at the moment is to create a text file and read/write from it but that will ruin the whole purpose of encryption as people can just open the text file and read it from there.
2. What does hash & salt means in encryption and how does it work? (a brief and simple explanation will do.)
3. What is the recommended way to implement username and password check?

I am sorry for the stupid questions. But i will greatly appreciate if you could answers my question.

Comment: Use databases for storing username and passwords. `sqlite3` should do it.

Comment: Why/what are hashes and salts: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYfMZx2hy_8

Comment: I'd recommend [scrypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrypt/) rather than devising your own hash/salt scheme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import getpass
import pickle
import hashlib
from os import path

def Encryption(data):
    return hashlib.sha512(data).hexdigest()

## First we check if the database exists.
if path.isfile('database.db'):
    with open('database.db', 'rb') as fh:
        db = pickle.load(fh)

## If it doesn't, we will create one.
else:
    ## First we create the desired variable.
    db = {'torxed' : Encryption('wham'), 'someoneelse' : Encryption('pass')}
    ## Then we open a filehandle to it.
    with open('database.db', 'wb') as fh:
        ## And then we dump the variable into the filehandle.
        ## This will keep the variable intact between sessions,
        ## meaning the next time you start your script, the variable will look the same.
        pickle.dump(db, fh)


## Then we ask the user for his/hers credentials.
user = raw_input('Username: ')
_pass = getpass.getpass('Password: ')

## If the user exists in the "db" and the decoded password
## Matches the logged in user, it's a-ok :)
if user in db and db[user] == Encryption(_pass):
    print('You logged in')
```

## Adding more users

```
import pickle, hashlib

def Encryption(data):
    return hashlib.sha512(data).hexdigest()

with open('database.db', 'rb') as fh:
    db = pickle.load(fh)

db['new_user'] = Encryption('password')

with open('database.db', 'wb') as fh:
    pickle.dump(db, fh)
```

Another way would be to use `sys.argv` to get the username and password from the commandline when addings users, in that case:

```
import pickle, hashlib, sys
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    raise ValueError('Need two parameters, username and password')

def Encryption(data):
    return hashlib.sha512(data).hexdigest()

with open('database.db', 'rb') as fh:
    db = pickle.load(fh)

db[sys.argv[1]] = Encryption(sys.argv[2])

with open('database.db', 'wb') as fh:
    pickle.dump(db, fh)
```

I should expand on this answer and explain that you should [salt passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594125/salt-and-hash-a-password-in-python) as well, and not just store them with a SHA hash.

Also note that passwords are strictly speaking "unsafe" when stored in memory, as there is no [SecureString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483723/securestring-for-storing-in-memory-and-presenting-passwords-or-something-else) *([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728164/securely-erasing-password-in-memory-python))* in Python as of writing this. But for basic purposes this answer still applies.

Comment: i prefer the username and password to be changeable.Not hard coded. So, i suppose i need some way to store the password. But thanks for the help

Comment: My edit does :) Forgot to add that portion to the file.
Note that, to completely secure your string you will need proper encryption, but you could do a `base64.b64encode` on the strings you store in the data, at least that will "obscure" it a bit.
Also, i'm assuming Python2.X here, `raw_input` is in fact `input()` on python3.x

Comment: yes i am using python 2.7 on windows xp. & thanks for the help

Comment: @ChrisAung You're welcome, made a small edit to the variable `pass`, it's not a valid variable name. :) so changed it to _pass

Comment: 1 more thing.. how do we add new user and password to the database?

Comment: @ChrisAung I added a small side-script that you can run to add more users. I also incorporated Kousik_Chodhury's solution on protecting the passwords (which, was a better idea then just b64 the string) :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do hashing like this.

```
import hashlib
def Encryption(data):
    return hashlib.sha224(data).hexdigest()
```

when you want to save the password then call this function and save the encode password.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), its an easy way to serialize things to a .pkl file which would be difficult to just open and read from.

Comment: That's **exactly** what my entire solution is based on? o0

Answer (score -1):

You could use htpasswd which is installed with apache or can be downloaded seperately. Use subprocess.check_output to run it and you can create Python functions to add users, remove them, verify they have given the correct password etc. Pass the -B option to enable salting and you will know that it's secure (unlike if you implement salts yourself).

Comment: I don't really see the point in using 3:d party software when Python had this built-in and there's Python modules to do the same job?
Also, if you need to use check_output to add main functionality in your code, you really gotta recosinder what you're about to do..