# how to create a password protected folder/file in linux using python

Tags: python

i would like to  create a password protected files(with some extentions) in a folder n when exer a new file is created in the folder it should be auto encrypted n password protected 
in linux using python
i have tried with pycrypto i can encrypt but i cant password protect the folder so plz help me with this 
here is the complete prog

```
def discover():
#file_path = ''
#print file_path
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'/root/Desktop/rakesh/rakeshp/dlp'):
       for file_name in files:
           file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
#print file_path        
file_list = []          
if file_path.endswith('.py'):
file_list.append(file_path)
dict = {}
status=""
for p in file_list:
    if not os.access(p, os.F_OK):
    dict[p]=status=status+"NOEXISTS"
    if(os.access(p,os.R_OK)):
    dict[p]=status=status+"READ," 
    if(os.access(p, os.W_OK)):
    dict[p]=status=status+"WRITE," 
    if (os.access(p, os.X_OK)):
    dict[p]=status=status+"EXECUTE"  
    elif os.access(p, os.F_OK) and not (os.access(p,os.R_OK)) and not (os.access(p, os.W_OK)) and not   (os.access(p, os.X_OK)):
    dict[p]=status=status="NOACCESS"
    status="" # Set blank before we enter the loop again            
    os.chmod(file_path,0444)                    
    for size in file_list:              
    size = os.path.getsize(file_path)       
    #print size                 
    #print (dict)
    in_filename = file_path
    #print in_filename
    if not out_filename:
    out_filename = in_filename + '.enc'
    iv = 16 * '\x00'
    #iv = bytes([random.randint(0, 0xFF) for i in range(16)])
    #print iv
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(struct.pack('<Q', size))
        outfile.write(iv)
        while True:
            chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
            if len(chunk) == 0:
            #print (chunk)
            break
            elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
            chunk += ' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
            #print (chunk)
            outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    discover()
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it depends what you mean by password protection. If you want to restrict access to an user based on a password, then all you need to do is to create the user and perform a `chown` on the file. Then the user has to be logged in on the system to be able to access it.

Otherwise, you could try something based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334482/password-protection-python) and encrypt the file based on the hash of the password.