# Is there an easy way to add a hide password type feature in python code?

Tags: python, security, python-2.7, password-protection

I'm creating a program that will require the user to enter a password. Is there a code that I can add in my program that way if someone is sitting behind the user or looking over his/her shoulder they don't see the password on the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the built-in [`getpass`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) module:

```
>>> import getpass
>>> x = getpass.getpass("enter password: ")
enter password:
>>> print(x)
'test'
```

Comment: can I get that encrypted??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16334504/1240162