# How to securely display a randomly generated password in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, passwords, securestring

By "securely", I mean in such a way that GC doesn't move it around in memory, copying is kept to a minimum, and it's removed from memory as soon as it's no longer needed.

I have the code for generating a random password, but I need to display it and I'd rather not use a `string` to do so. The password is currently generated in a `SecureString` which I can put in a fixed/pinned buffer to work with. What's the most secure way I can render it to the user?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6483723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to display a `SecureString` without converting it to a normal string. In any event, Microsoft themselves don't even recommend secure `SecureString` anymore. [This](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md) is linked to from the [official msdn documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.8):

> ## DE0001: SecureString shouldn't be used
>
> ### Motivation
>
> - The purpose of [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring) is to avoid having secrets stored in the process   memory as plain text.
> - However, even on Windows, [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring) doesn't exist as an OS concept.
>
>   - It just makes the window getting the plain
>       text shorter; it doesn't fully
>       prevent it as .NET still has to convert the string to a plain text
>       representation.
>   - The benefit is that the plain text representation doesn't hang around
>       as an instance of [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string) -- the lifetime of the native buffer is
>       shorter.
> - The contents of the array is unencrypted except on .NET Framework.
>
>   - In .NET Framework, the contents of the internal char array is encrypted.
>       .NET doesn't support encryption in all environments, either
>       due to missing APIs or key management issues.
>
> ### Recommendation
>
> Don't use [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring) for new code. When porting
>   code to .NET Core, consider that the contents of the array are not
>   encrypted in memory.
>
> The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and
>   instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or
>   Windows authentication.

`SecureString` isn't really effective protection for sensitive information, it just limits the attack window a bit and obfuscates things.

My personal opinion is that if you are going to show it to the user anyway, you should really be worrying about how accessible it is inside the application. And, in general, the safety of the memory of an application is the responsibility of the OS and the physical security of the hardware. If you need to worry about unauthorized access to application memory, you already have a much bigger security problem.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know they were all but depricated. Thanks for the tip. Thankfully this is just a learning project to see what's involved in making a password manager application, so it won't ever be used to store real user data or sensitive information.